# Laravel, how to determine if query builder already contains "order"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to to go a default order if a relationship doesn't already have an order. But if it does I don't use the default.

```
$q = $this->items();

if (empty($q->orders)) {
    $q = $q->order();
}
```

Note that `order()` is just a default method in the a `BaseModel` class. For some reason when I try to call the `orders` property on the query builder it says `Undefined property` even though it's a public property in the `Builder` class.

Not sure why, or how I can check for this.

EDIT:

I setup a full example in a route:

```
class Test extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {}

$router->get('/test', function () {
    $test = new Test;
    $q = $test->select('id')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    $bindings = $q->getRawBindings();
    var_dump($bindings);
    return 'test';
});
```

The dump just spits out the query builder object rather than the bindings?

Comment: Then you would be executing on a `Collection` not on the `Builder`. Plus I need to inspect the query before execution. @Zombaya.

Comment: You are not using the query builder, you are using Eloquent wich uses other functions and the query builder under the hood.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some toying around, finally got it going.

So actually it's an instance of `Eloquent\Builder` not `Query\Builder` so need to do:

```
$q->getQuery()->orders
```

This gets you access to the query object.

Comment: To retrieve the `ORDER` clauses on a relationship, the required notation is, e.g.: `User::find(1)->comments()->getQuery()->getQuery()->orders`. The second call to `getQuery()` is necessary because we're transcending from an `Eloquent\Builder` to a `Query\Builder` in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very safe to use properties directly. You can use the [getRawBindings](http://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_getRawBindings) function for this.

Using the following code you get all bindings in a flattened array:

```
$q->getRawBindings();
```

Now you just need to filter out the `orders`.

Comment: This is just returning an array `Array([0] => 1)`. Not sure why it's doing that, when I echo `->toSql()` below that I see the proper query with multiple `where` and `order` clauses.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you need `getRawBindings`. I have updated my response.

Comment: How to `filter` out `orders`? It seems like the same object as when I just print out `$q`.

Comment: `$q->getRawBindings()` will return an array with `key => value` pairs. This array has a key `orders`, if this value is not null and bigger than 0 then there are orders in this query.

Comment: Right, but it's not returning the key/value array pair, it's returning the builder object for some reason when I do `print_r($q->getRawBindings());` I really have no idea why. Aside from that when I'm in the `getRawBindings()` function an print from there I see the bindings but not for `orders` for some reason.

Comment: I've added a simple full example.